# Local VCS for one person use

Tags: version-control

Not really a programming question per se, so pls advice if I should move it to some other stackexchange...

Is there a recommended Version Control solution running on a local (Windows XP/Vista/7) machine for the use of a single person only? I may not have internet access on the box so online repos like Github or Mercurial are out of the question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Subversion locally if you really want a server based solution. If you're running 100% local on a single machine then Hg and Git will work just fine. You don't need to pair them with a service like GitHub or Bitbucket.

The [Mercurial QuickStart](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/QuickStart) (section 3) covers how to set up Mercurial locally.

For Windows I'd recommend [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) as a way to quickly get a SVN server on your machine.

Comment: +1 for VisualSVN - if you're a guy who likes SVN, VSVN couldn't make it easier for your side projects.

Comment: I actually use both. Hg for source code, which merge well, and SVN for binary files that don't.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give these a try

Comment: TortoiseHg is really nice to use a local VCS with Mercurial, and later you can share your work very easily.

Comment: @Jazz. Yes. I forgot about that. I also use SCCS packages for VS:  http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ for SVN and http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html for Mercurial.

Answer (score 1):

Git and Mercurial can both be used locally. I use SVN with TortoiseSVN, which works fine for a single developer; I've also got some stuff in Mercurial, because I'm experimenting with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial can work well on a local environment. There is no "central server" for a Hg repository, so you can just create one in your project folder, and commit as and when you like. It also integrates very well into Windows Explorer and (if you use it) Visual Studio using TortoiseHg and VisualHg respectively.

You can even implement push/pull functionality in your repositories locally, by storing your repository in a different folder.

**Edit** - I have used Mercurial locally, and I've also used it by storing my central repositories on an external hard drive. It works identically over a network and between folders (or hard drives) on your local PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Subversion (i.e SVN) client and server on your own machine and start using them.

Svnadmin for managing svn server is also easy to use, And there are plenty of binary distributions for subversion on windows (both server and client)

That is what I suggest as it helps you learn SVN and use it anywhere else.